# Getting all the objects in the JavaScript from Django

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to get all my object models from the database and store them in someway, the model I have is:

```
class Device (models.Model):
    patientId = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    deviceId = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=100)
    hour = models.DateTimeField()
    type = models.IntegerField()
    glucoseValue = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm sending them in views.py:

```
device_list = list(Device.objects.all())
context = {"filename": filename,
           "deviceList": device_list,
               }
```

In JS I managed to get each object like that:

```
{% for item in deviceList%}
console.log( "{{item}}" );
{% endfor %}
```

What I want is to store those objects in some way, but I don't really know how, because they are coming like that Model object (1).

Comment: try `{{item.patientId}}` or `{{item.hour}}`. btw. perentID sounds like it supposed to be a ForeignKey.

Comment: I already managed to access them like that, but I want to store them, not display them.

Comment: google "How to send json response - django" and on the js side use `json.parse({{deviceList}})`... https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse than you can work with all the data in js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert django model to javascript object, you can do it in many way, but I recommend you something like this:

in views.py convert object to json dict:

```
"deviceList": json.dumps([model_to_dict(x) for x in device_list])
```

In HTML template you can do something like this:

```
<script>
const deviceList = JSON.parse('{{ deviceList|safe }}')
console.log(deviceList)
</script>
```

Comment: It seems that "Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable".

Comment: I managed to make it work, by using a json_serial, thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: thats the stuff I was talking about. Sharpek very nice from you to type it out and give a proper answer. Would be even better with the use of a serializer and something like DRF but take my upvote anyway :)